# vue i18n - using it as a javascript object (not inside the template)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible to use vue, vue-i18n only with javascript (as an object), not in the template ?

I want to use it in something like window.confirm, is that possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

yes it's possible, i never used the plugin, but it looks pretty straightforward:

first you create the instance:

```
// Ready translated locale messages
const messages = {
  en: {
    message: {
      greeting: 'hi {name}'
    }
  },
  es: {
    message: {
      greeting: 'hola {name}'
    }
  }
}

// Create VueI18n instance with options
const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'es', // set locale
  messages, // set locale messages
})
```

(be aware 'const' is es6)

Then you can use it in any js where i18n var exists:

```
i18n.t('greeting', { name: 'kazupon' }) // -> hola kazupon
```

Doc:

http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/en/started.html

http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/en/migrations.html

Answer (score 2):

Using inside a component for Version **6.x** or Later:

```
mounted() {
    this.$i18n.t('path', 'en', { foo: 'bar' })
}
```

Or

```
mounted() {
    this.$t('path', 'en', { foo: 'bar' })
}
```

---

For version **5.x**:

```
mounted() {
    Vue.t('path', 'en', { foo: 'bar' })
}
```

Source: https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/149#issuecomment-300096155

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
Import i18n.js configuration file where you need to get 18n values, (Where you've configured i18n With Vue.js project)

```
import i18n from '@/plugins/i18n'
```

Using @ to get a path from the root.

Then

Attach values with

```
i18n.t('salesOrder'),
```